# How to grab or store coordinates in mcreator from a 2d arraylist?

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I am new to mcreator and have been tinkering, however I cannot find anything with a solution to my problem.

I am just trying to make a lumber axe which breaks all connecting logs to the original broken block. I have the logic I just don't understand how to convert it into mcreator - fabric as it keeps throwing errors at me.

the error is that I add an array of coordinates to another array, then later I try to collect these coordinates but it throws errors.

-Note I am using the Array List addon: https://mcreator.net/plugin/65659/arraylists

This is what I have so far (In mcreator block form):

```
Local Array List : logs_to_destroy
Local Array List : need_to_check
Local Array List : current_position
Local Array List : temp_position
Event trigger (When block is broken)
Clear Get Local: logs_to_destroy
Clear Get Local: need_to_check
Clear Get Local: current_position
Clear Get Local: temp_position
Add Value >x to Get Local current_position
Add Value >y to Get Local: current_position
Add Value >z to Get Local: current_position
Add Value >Get Local: current_position to Get Local: need_to_check
//testing purposes
Set Local: current_position to Get the value at index [0] of Get Local: need_to_check
//error that it cannot set it to a reference of an object
```